# RegEx to force validate float value of 5.3 format (i.e. 12345.123)

Tags: regex

I am trying to create an RegEx to validate one of my input form field, which would allow either Character value (i.e. TBA or NA) or a straight whole number maximum 9 digits (this is set by field limit vtype) or in 5.3 format, such as 12345.123 or 12345.001 and so on. The below is what I've compiled from the searches:

```
/^([A-Z])|([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]{1,2}))?$/i;
```

This seemed to work fine with Alpha and whole number but when it comes to 5.3 format, I wanted to make value like 12345.1 or 12345.12 invalid and force it to only accept the value with the proper 5.3 format like "12345.123"

I am not very good with RegEx and solely depended on searching online and combining result so any assistance will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Examples of valid matches?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: We have idiomatic python, idiomatic awk; why never idiomatic regex? I'd upvote one but none of them are pretty enough (yet)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?:[A-Z]+|[0-9]{5}(?:[0-9]|\.)[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,8})$/i;
```

Comment: Now it does. <°))))))>

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to slightly modify the suggested to fit what I needed to do!

Answer (score 1):

```
^([A-Za-z]+|\d{1,9}|\d{5}\.\d{3})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/VWtj4XNbb1_7mPvB)

Comment: Thanks for the visual explanation. It has definitely helped me to understand RegEx a bit better!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression:

```
^(?:[A-Z]+|[0-9]{1,9}|[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{3})$
```

Notice the entire match is grouped using `(?:)` so that this expression matches only complete input and not partial text.

So this expression matches only uppercase letters `[A-Z]+`.

Or it matches 9 complete digits `[0-9]{1,9}`.

Or it matches 5 digits followed by a dot `.` followed by 3 digits `[0-9]{5}\.([0-9]{3})`.

**[Regex 101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gU9nM3)**

Comment: @cbuckley Ask and you shall receive :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helps and the explanation (plus the 101 Demo weblink). It definitely helped me understand much better of RegEx!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the wrong part: `/^([A-Z])|([0-9]+)(.([0-9]{1,2}))?$/i;`. You are basically saying that only one or two digits are allowed after the decimal point. So here it is:

```
/^([A-Z]+)$|^(\d+\.\d{3})$|^(\d{1,9})$/i;
```

Sample [here](http://rubular.com/r/MGD5BpNXmS).

Answer (score 0):

So you want there to be 5 numbers on the left hand side of the decimal, and 3 on the right hand side?

How about this:

```
/^([A-Z]+)|([0-9]{1,9})|([0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{3})$/i
```

I find it clearer if the "1-9 numbers" and "5.3 decimal" formats are specified separately. Adding `{n}` (curly braces) after a pattern says you want to match n occurrences of that pattern.

Note: I haven't tested the above.

Comment: Thanks for the helps and the explanation Mr. hdgarrood!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
`^([A-Z]+|[0-9]{1,9}|(\d{5}.\d{3}))$`

Comment: Thanks for the helps Mr. Malinovskij!